# Kendo UI Editor ImageBrowser path issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm having problems passing one string parameter from view to controller.

View:

```
@model ImageModel

@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
          .Name("EditorCustom")
          .ImageBrowser(imagEditorImageBrowserControllereBrowser => imageBrowser
            .Image(Model.fullpath)
            .Read("Read", "ImageBrowser")
            .Upload("Upload2", "ImageBrowser")
            .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ImageBrowser")
          )
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 740px;height:440px" })
          .Tools(tools => tools
                    .ViewHtml()
                    .CustomButton(cb => cb.Name("new").ToolTip(Html.RawLocalized(GlobalMessageKeys.InsertTable).ToString()).Exec(@<text>
                function(e) {
                    $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
                }
                </text>))
               )
  )
```

ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace App.ViewModels
{
    public class ImageModel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string fullpath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload2(string path, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {
                UploadResource uploadRes = new UploadResource();
                uploadRes.Path = path;
                uploadRes.StreamFile = file.InputStream;
                uploadRes.Name = file.FileName;

                ServiceLocator.MaintenanceService.UploadResource(uploadRes);
            }

            catch (Exception)
            { 

            }

            return Content("");
        }
```

The controller class inherits from EditorImageBrowserController that is a DLL, but I want to upload and read images by myself without using DLL, so I write in the controller a new method called "Upload2" that recieves the file that pass correctly and the path string that is always null. I was trying to send it by the mvc kendo code ".Image(Model.fullpath)" in the view but nothing and I don't found a solution yet.

Comment: Stoping eating exceptions would be a first step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late, this is more for future googlers.

You could create your own controller, and override default with something like.

```
 public class YourOwnImageBrowserController : EditorImageBrowserController
{
    //
    // GET: /YourOwnImageBrowserController/
    private const string contentFolderRoot = "~/images/yourfolder";
    public override string ContentPath
    {
        get
        {
            return contentFolderRoot;
        }
    }

}
```

Then in your Editor use it.

```
   .Read("Read", "YourOwnImageBrowserController")
   .Create("Create", "YourOwnImageBrowserController")
   .Destroy("Destroy", "YourOwnImageBrowserController")
   .Upload("Upload", "YourOwnImageBrowserController")
   .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "YourOwnImageBrowserController"))
```

Kendo libraries handles all attached events.